For VScode "Code Actions" in markdown, how to add `-` bullet via popover context menu?
In VScode, on linux, in a .md file I want to select a word or a line and control+. (or click the yellow lightbulb) to invoke the Code Actions context menu …
… and then be able to select something like unordered list item in order to insert a "- " hyphen and space before the word or line.
I think I have to edit the system extensions here:
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/markdown-basics/language-configuration.json
… but I have no idea what to add their to get this simple formatting command into the code-actions menu.
I would also like to be able to select multiple lines and have codeActions menu offer me a numbered list option that increments from 1., 2., 3., etc.
How can I achieve either or both of these?
